What the good terms to depict the manner someone can reply to me if I'm asking for a location, depending the way he is replying to me?
I am on a road or anywhere, and I want to go to a location (a shop or a place).
I'm asking someone how to get there. If my helper has a:

"cartesian" (?) vision of things, he can reply to me: "The place you're looking for is at lat 45.228416° North, long 2.15579° East".

"polar" (?) vision, draw his arm in a direction (that makes an angle with the direction I'm facing myself) and say: "It's that way, for 500 meters"

"?" vision, he can tell me: "Follow the road you are on for 400 meters, then turn right and continue 150 meters"


What are the good terms to depict the manner my helper is replying to me in each case?

This question doesn't seem off-topic here (I'm actually curious about possible answers), but it might be better-suited to the Geographic Information Systems SE. ... BTW: A common, informal way to phrase polar directions is "as the crow flies".

I'd call the third method, "landmark based"

Here's my take.

Absolute spherical coordinates
Relative spherical coordinates
Compound spherical coordinates

I guess we can call it the ARC system. Also these distinguishing words are all the same number of letters, so you know it's good.

Classically terms as:  Global Spherical Cartesian (needs a collection of euclidean cartesian local maps ), Cartanian Riemannian ( uses a spherical comoving frame with Riemann normal coordinates), Wienerian Langrangian (minimizes time by weights of  possible paths) ;-|
